# LINQ query help (LINQ to SQL)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm not really familiar with LINQ, but I'm currently working on an ASP.NET project and using LINQ to SQL as ORM (I'm building a route planning application). I have a problem creating a query the way I need it, so maybe anyone could give me a hint how to achieve this. My current query looks like this:

```
var results = from lift in db.Lift
              where lift.StartTime > DateTime.Now
                    && lift.Route.Stop.Any(o => o.Location.Name.ToLower().Contains(origin))
                    && lift.Route.Stop.Any(d => d.Location.Name.ToLower().Contains(destination))
              select lift;
```

This query works and does its work. The extension I would need is the following: each Stop has a field called Order which determines the Stop order in a specific Route. My query should select all Lifts which Route has Stops which match order and destination (thats what the query does so far) AND where the origin Stop has a lower Order number than the destination Stop. Can I do this with LINQ or do I have to filter the results afterwards?

Thanks in advance,
Mathias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head.. try something like this (could probably be simplified):

```
var results = from lift in db.Lift
              let originStop = lift.Route.Stop.
                  FirstOrDefault(o => o.Location.Name.ToLower().Contains(origin))
              let destinationStop = lift.Route.Stop.
                  FirstOrDefault(d => d.Location.Name.ToLower().Contains(destination))
              where lift.StartTime > DateTime.Now
                    && originStop != null
                    && destinationStop != null
                    && originStop.OrderNumber < destinationStop.OrderNumber
              select lift;
```